# How to parse xml to pandas dataframe using beatiful soup

Tags: python, pandas, xml, beautifulsoup

I have:

```
xml_data = """<address_details sequence_number="1" match_indicator="L">
    <address_input id="ADI" address_details="street address and postcode" />
    <address_matched id="ADO" address_key="123" house_name="" house_number="" street_1="" street_2="" district="" posttown="" county="" postcode="AB1 2CD" address_type="" />
    <electoral_roll id="ELR" name_match_indicator="A" title="" forename="firstName" second_name="J" surname="LastName" date_of_birth="" period="19-21" junior_senior="" />
    <electoral_roll id="ELR" name_match_indicator="C" title="" forename="FirstName" second_name="M" surname="MILES" date_of_birth="" period="19-21" junior_senior="" />
    <telephone_data id="TLR" title="" forename="D" second_name="" surname="LastName" date_of_birth="" std_code="******" local_number="*****" tps="" date_loaded="2020-02-07" LineType="N" />
    <insight id="INR" name_match_indicator="A" title="MR" forename="firstName" second_name="J" surname="LastName" date_of_birth="YYYY-MM-DD" />
    <coded_insight_for_id_verification id="IDC" number_of_accounts="6"  />
  </address_details>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data,  "html.parser")
```

I want to loop through each `child?` node (not sure terminology for `address matched`, `electoral_roll`, etc are with respect to the `address_details`), and create a small dataframe for each child.

My current method is:

```
ls_er = []
er = soup.find_all('electoral_roll')
for i in range(len(er)):
    ls_er.append(er[i].attrs)

ls_ai = []
er = soup.find_all('address_input')
for i in range(len(er)):
    ls_ai.append(er[i].attrs)

ls_am = []
er = soup.find_all('address_matched')
for i in range(len(er)):
    ls_am.append(er[i].attrs)

ls_tele = []
er = soup.find_all('telephone_data')
for i in range(len(er)):
    ls_tele.append(er[i].attrs)

ls_i = []
er = soup.find_all('insight')
for i in range(len(er)):
    ls_i.append(er[i].attrs)

ls_cofi = []
er = soup.find_all('coded_insight_for_id_verification')
for i in range(len(er)):
    ls_cofi.append(er[i].attrs)

pd.DataFrame(ls_ai)
pd.DataFrame(ls_am)
pd.DataFrame(ls_er)
pd.DataFrame(ls_tele)
pd.DataFrame(ls_i)
pd.DataFrame(ls_cofi)
```

This works ok, but there are 2 issues:

- there may/not be extra/fewer child nodes (ie `electoral_roll` might not be present, or `new_category` might be present)
- is there a way to loop through all of the child nodes and perform requested operation?

pseudocode idea:

```
num = len(soup.number_children_nodes)
ls_child_soup0, ls_child_soup1 ,,, ls_chld_soupn = ([] for i in range(num))
for child in soup:
    child_soup = soup.find_all(child)
    for i in range(len(child_soup)):
        ls_child_soup0.append(child_soup[i].attrs)
```

I would like to return a few dataframes that look like:

[image]

Comment: Can you edit  your question and show the exact expected output based on `xml_data`?

Comment: edit to show outputs desired

Comment: I don't understand - you want 6 different one-row DFs?

Comment: that's correct .

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify (e.g. sample text) what output you expect?

You can certainly make your code simpler:

```py
address_details_nodes = soup.find_all("address_details")
child_nodes = (address.findChildren() for address in address_details)
attributes = [pd.DataFrame([child.attrs for child in children]) for children in child_nodes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of BeautifulSoup, I guess you'll have to do something like this:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd

doc = etree.XML(xml_data)
for entry in doc.xpath('/address_details//*'):
    exp = f'//{entry.tag}'
    print(pd.read_xml(xml_data, xpath=exp))
```

That should output what I believe is your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

**Pandas only solution**
Parse xml into a single dataframe and then get slices from it (in 2 different ways)

Read xml into single df

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
xml_data = """<address_details sequence_number="1" match_indicator="L">
    <address_input id="ADI" address_details="street address and postcode" />
    <address_matched id="ADO" address_key="123" house_name="lilo" house_number="21" street_1="Eve st" street_2="" district="B" posttown="" county="x" postcode="AB1 2CD" address_type="" />
    <address_matched id="ADO" address_key="456" house_name="ada" house_number="32" street_1="sam st" street_2="" district="C" posttown="" county="X" postcode="AB1 2CD" address_type="" />
    <electoral_roll id="ELR" name_match_indicator="A" title="" forename="firstName" second_name="J" surname="LastName" date_of_birth="" period="19-21" junior_senior="" />
    <electoral_roll id="ELR" name_match_indicator="C" title="" forename="FirstName" second_name="M" surname="MILES" date_of_birth="" period="19-21" junior_senior="" />
    <telephone_data id="TLR" title="" forename="D" second_name="" surname="LastName" date_of_birth="" std_code="******" local_number="*****" tps="" date_loaded="2020-02-07" LineType="N" />
    <telephone_data id="TLR" title="" forename="F" second_name="D" surname="LastName" date_of_birth="1970-01-01" std_code="******" local_number="*****" tps="" date_loaded="2023-02-07" LineType="N" />
    <coded_insight_for_id_verification id="IDC" number_of_accounts="6"  />
  </address_details>"""
df = pd.read_xml(StringIO(xml_data), dtype=object, xpath="//address_details/*")
#print(df)
#[8 rows x 26 columns]
```

Get results by taking slices with attributes ranges, for `address_matched` element first attr is `address_key`, last attribute is `address_type`.

```
print(df[df.id == 'ADO'].loc[:,"address_key":"address_type"])
print("----------------------_")
print(df[df.id == 'ELR'].loc[:,"name_match_indicator":"junior_senior"])
print("----------------------_")
print(df[df.id == 'TLR'].loc[:,"title":"LineType"])
```

Result

```
  address_key house_name house_number street_1 street_2 district posttown county postcode address_type
1         123       lilo           21   Eve st      NaN        B      NaN      x  AB1 2CD          NaN
2         456        ada           32   sam st      NaN        C      NaN      X  AB1 2CD          NaN
----------------------_
  name_match_indicator title   forename second_name   surname date_of_birth period junior_senior
3                    A   NaN  firstName           J  LastName           NaN  19-21           NaN
4                    C   NaN  FirstName           M     MILES           NaN  19-21           NaN
----------------------_
  title forename second_name   surname date_of_birth period junior_senior std_code local_number  tps date_loaded LineType
5   NaN        D         NaN  LastName           NaN   None          None   ******        *****  NaN  2020-02-07        N
6   NaN        F           D  LastName    1970-01-01   None          None   ******        *****  NaN  2023-02-07        N
```

**ALTERNATIVE**: Reindex df over `id` column and take slices on index and column ranges

```
df.set_index('id', append=False, inplace=True)
print(df.loc['ADO',"address_key":"address_type"])
print("----------------------_")
print(df.loc['ELR',"name_match_indicator":"junior_senior"])
print("----------------------_")
print(df.loc['TLR',"title":"LineType"])
```

Result

```
    address_key house_name house_number street_1 street_2 district posttown county postcode address_type
id                                                                                                      
ADO         123       lilo           21   Eve st      NaN        B      NaN      x  AB1 2CD          NaN
ADO         456        ada           32   sam st      NaN        C      NaN      X  AB1 2CD          NaN
----------------------_
    name_match_indicator title   forename second_name   surname date_of_birth period junior_senior
id                                                                                                
ELR                    A   NaN  firstName           J  LastName           NaN  19-21           NaN
ELR                    C   NaN  FirstName           M     MILES           NaN  19-21           NaN
----------------------_
    title forename second_name   surname date_of_birth period junior_senior std_code local_number  tps date_loaded LineType
id                                                                                                                         
TLR   NaN        D         NaN  LastName           NaN   None          None   ******        *****  NaN  2020-02-07        N
TLR   NaN        F           D  LastName    1970-01-01   None          None   ******        *****  NaN  2023-02-07        N
```

If XML attributes are not always on the same order then all column names can be used

```
print(df[df.id == 'ADO'][["id", "address_key",  "house_name", "house_number",  "street_1", "street_2",  "district", "posttown",  "county", "postcode",  "address_type"]])
print(df[df.id == 'ELR'][["id", "name_match_indicator",  "title", "forename",  "second_name", "surname",  "date_of_birth", "period",  "junior_senior"]])
print(df[df.id == 'TLR'][["id", "title",  "forename", "second_name",  "surname", "date_of_birth",  "std_code", "local_number",  "tps", "date_loaded",  "LineType"]])
```